# Duplicate SQL Record Entries with in 3 days

Tags: sql-server

Table has following structure

```
ID, OrderNumber, PFirstName, PLastName, Product, LastDateModified
```

This information is populated into my SQL Server database by a XML import file and is created when the front end hits 'Enter'. But someone on the front has been seeing an error and then hitting Cancel and re-submitting the order with new information.

Now, the first order is in the Database because they didn't cancel it out on the backend first.

How can I find the any duplicate `OrderNumber, PFirstName, PLastName, Product` within 3 days of any `lastdatemodified` entry?

Comment: so ... order number is duplicated?  (I hope not it's the PK right?) or do you mean the order is duplicated and the order number varies but you need to find it as if it was a duplicate?  Sample data expected results always helps clarify question and reduce questions... about your question...

Comment: The ordernumber is not duplicated, the same order was placed within 3 days for the same pfname, plastname, product...  and the customer is getting 2 of the same product when they only ordered 1.  We need to determine how many times this is happening and the number of times the customer has not notified us of the problem and kept the second product as well but only paid for the 1st

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A self join with a simple where clause.

Assuming the ORDER numbers are not duplicated and that's what  you're looking for.

```
SELECT A.ID as A_ID
     , A.orderNumber as OriginalOrder
     , B.ID as B_ID
     , B.OrderNumber as PossibleDuplicatedOrder
FROM TBL A
INNER JOIN TBL B
  on A.PFirstName = B.PfirstName
 AND A.PLastName = B.PLastName
 AND A.Product = B.Product
 AND A.LastDateMOdified < B.LastDateModified
WHERE datediff(day,A.LastDateModified,B.LastDateModified) <=3
```

Logically this self joins and to eliminate A-->B and B-->A duplication casued by self joins we use a < so that all of the records in alias A have a date earlier than that in B when the other fields are equal, and then we simply look for those that have a datediff of <=3.

However if multiple duplicates exist for the same order such as

```
A-->B
B-->C
```

You'll see duplication in the results such as (but only if all 3 are w/in 3 days)

```
A-->B
B-->C
A-->C
```

But I don't see this as a bad thing given what you're attempting to recover from.

I'm not sure how to determine if it's been cancelled or backed out so you'll have to set other limits for that as they weren't specified in the question.

Comment: Thanks you... This was perfect.